# Android: Get Supported Video Sizes

Tags: android, android-camera, video-capture

Hopefully this is an easy question to answer. How can I get a list of supported video capture sizes in Android? Also, how can I get a list of supported video capture frame rates? I'm looking for the equivalent to `Camera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes()`, only for video...

I need a solution that will work with API Level 7, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information on supported video size use the API (Camera.Parameter)-

```
public List<Camera.Size> getSupportedVideoSizes ()
```

For the FPS I am not really sure but changing the preview fps in the Camera.Parameter might change the FPS of capture as well.. (If it does then you can use the getSupportedPreviewFpsRange() to find out the supported frame rates..)

Comment: Unfortunately, that only works as of API 11. Here's a solution that someone else found. I'm trying it now; perhaps it will work for you! http://stackoverflow.com/a/5946823/234258

Comment: Worked for API level 7, as I requested. Thanks.

Comment: can use `MediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(8);` for setting fps