# How to get supported video camera resolutions in android?

Tags: java, android, camera

I am writing an app where I am allowing the user to capture video using the phones camera.  I am using my own code to record the video as opposed to Androids built in camera app.

Everything is working OK except I need to be able to access the list of supported camera resolutions so I can choose at runtime which one to use.  I am looking for something like `getSupportedPictureSizes()` but for video.  Android 3.0 has this functionality but I am looking for something for 2.2.

As of right now I am using `CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH / QUALITY_LOW`,  but this only gives me two options and on the phones I have been testing on, the file sizes are at each extreme.(QUALITY_LOW is 216 kb/s and QUALITY_HIGH is > 3 MB/s)

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thank You!

Answer (score 10):

Did you try to use the [`getSupportedVideoSizes()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedVideoSizes()) from `Camera.Parameters` class?

```
public List<Camera.Size> getSupportedVideoSizes()
```

This method returns a list of Size objects. It will return `null` if the camera does not have separate preview and video output. [The answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22022062/822005) indicates that when this returns `null` you may use the [`getSupportedPreviewSizes()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes()) list.

Comment: Thanks! but unfortunately that wasnt implemented until API 11 (Android 3) and I am on API 8 (2.2).  I found that the other night and it took me a half an hour of cursing to figure out it wasnt in my api.

Comment: Ok  I think I figured it out.  It seems to work correctly on the phones I have been testing with.

Comment: I tried this on the Nexus S with Android 4.0.3, and it *always* returns null!

Comment: Because: _Returns: a list of Size object if camera has separate preview and video output; otherwise, null is returned._

Comment: At this time that's all deprecated: Camera and Camera.Parameters

Answer (score 5):

Ok  I think I figured it out.  It seems to work correctly on the phones I have been testing on.

```
List<Size> tmpList = camera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();

    final List<Size> sizeList = new Vector<Size>();

    //compair the apsect ratio of the candidate sizes against the real ratio
    Double aspectRatio = (Double.valueOf(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()) / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth());
    for(int i=0; i<tmpList.size(); i++){
        Double tmpRatio = Double.valueOf(tmpList.get(i).height) / tmpList.get(i).width;
        if(Math.abs(aspectRatio - tmpRatio) < .15){
            sizeList.add(tmpList.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This only works on some phones. My HTC Desire Z will crash when setting many of the modes listed by this method.

Comment: I believe this is the code that I am still using.  On some devices (Motorolla devices seem to do this) getSupportedPreviewSizes() seems to return some sizes that will not work, causing the video to be corrupted with green lines and such.  What problems are you having?