# Android getSupportedVideoSizes always returns null

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I need some help with the `MediaRecorder` class on Android.

I try to use `getSupportedVideoSizes` to get the list of supported video sizes, but it always returns null.

In testing, the following devices return `null` when `getSupportedVideoSizes` is queried:

- Galaxy Nexus (Android 4.2)
- HTC One Mini (Android 4.4.2)
- HTCEVOV4G (Android 4.0.3)

Comment: Here's some discussion on the topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934829/how-to-get-supported-video-camera-resolutions-in-android .

Comment: Hi thank you for your help, but unfortunately I have seen that post. But how can I set separate preview and video output? that is what I can not understand ... because they all use that function getSupportedVideoSizes but for me it keeps returning null ...

Comment: Did you see last comment there left by YShinkarev? There it was mentioned that in some cases ``getSupportedVideoSizes`` returns null by design.

Comment: so what are you saying is that this is dependent on the phone ?

Comment: Unfortunately, if I understood documentation correctly, this is a HW related decision whether null is returned by default.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[The documentation for `Camera.getSupportedVideoSizes()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedVideoSizes()) which reads,

> **Returns**
>   a list of Size object if camera has separate preview and video output; otherwise, null is returned.

is not entirely clear. However, it means that if `Camera.getSupportedVideoSizes()` returns null, then the camera's supported preview sizes and video sizes are the same; in this case,  to get the list of supported video sizes, use `Camera.getSupportedPreviewSizes()`.

Sample code:

```
public List<Size> getSupportedVideoSizes(Camera camera) {
    if (camera.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes() != null) {
        return camera.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes();
    } else {
        // Video sizes may be null, which indicates that all the supported 
        // preview sizes are supported for video recording.
        return camera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    }
}
```

Comment: The description in the android documentation is downright preposterous!

Comment: Good answer and explanation... That is a little catch that is easily overlooked, especially when your development devices return a list for getSupportedVideoSizes(). Turns out that Samsung and others return null, so my app was having to just guess the picture size to use, which resulted in settings that weren't supported on all devices. It's working solidly now when using getSupportedPreviewSizes() to handle the null cases.

Comment: Ridiculous documentation requires this kind of awesome digging. Thank you +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Or just use

```
mediarecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
```

to set the best resolution automatically.