# CameraBridgeViewBase get all supported resolution Android

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera

I have an app which needs to know all the camera supported resolutions - how do i access that data?

any suggestions?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934829/how-to-get-supported-video-camera-resolutions-in-android

Comment: Thank you but thats not it,It cant be applied to camerabridgeviewbase

Answer (score 0):

```
import static android.hardware.Camera
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
```

I think you can use a hardware-camera beside the OpenCV-camera.

```
CameraBridgeViewBase cameraBridgeViewBase;
List list;
arrayListForWidth = new ArrayList<>();
arrayListForHeight = new ArrayList<>();
```

[Android getSupportedVideoSizes always returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263521/android-getsupportedvideosizes-always-returns-null/22022062#22022062)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5934967/10751265

Use both getSupportedVideoSizes and getSupportedPreviewSizes

```
if (Camera.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes() != null || cam_index.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes() != null) {
    if (cam_index.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes() != null)
        list = cam_index.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes();
    else
        list = cam_index.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
                
    for (Object e_list : list) {
        arrayListForWidth.add(((Camera.Size) e_list).width);
        arrayListForHeight.add(((Camera.Size) e_list).height);
    }
}
```

After getting arraylists for width and height, you can use them for OpenCV-camera

```
cameraBridgeViewBase.setMaxFrameSize(arrayListForWidth.get(i), arrayListForHeight.get(i));
```